# R: is it possible to merge to 2 variables in one?

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, dplyr, merge

Is it possible to merge 2 variables in a unique one?

This is my dataset

```
`City Name`  `Average amount` `Nominal Difference`   `%`   `Real Wage`    `Real Difference`

Barletta           2457            1007            41.0        27.5              11.3
Caserta            2445            910             37.2        27.4              10.2
Avellino           2363            1016            43.0        26.5              11.4
Lecce              2342            981             41.9        26.2              11.0
Benevento          2335            1157            49.6        26.1              13.0
Isernia            2334            1078            46.2        26.1              12.1
L'Aquila           2324            1010            43.5        26.0              11.3
Catanzaro          2310            1533            66.3        25.9              17.2
Campobasso         2259            1106            49.0        25.3              12.4
Enna               2242            922             41.1        25.1              10.3
```

I'd like to have the percentage (with a plus sign and inside parentesis) in the column of Nominal Difference.

To better explain
[image: TABLE]

What I'm looking for is

```
`City Name`  `Average amount` `Nominal Difference`   `Real Wage`    `Real Difference`

Barletta           2457            1007 (+41.0%)        27.5              11.3
Caserta            2445            910  (+37.2%)        27.4              10.2
Avellino           2363            1016 (+43.0%)        26.5              11.4
Lecce              2342            981  (+41.9%)        26.2              11.0
Benevento          2335            1157 (+49.6%)        26.1              13.0
Isernia            2334            1078 (+46.2%)        26.1              12.1
L'Aquila           2324            1010 (+43.5%)        26.0              11.3
Catanzaro          2310            1533 (+66.3%)        25.9              17.2
Campobasso         2259            1106 (+49.0%)        25.3              12.4
Enna               2242            922  (+41.1%)        25.1              10.3
```

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

```
> dput(f)
structure(list(`City Name` = c("Barletta -Andria-Trani", "Caserta", 
"Avellino", "Lecce", "Benevento", "Isernia", "L'Aquila", "Catanzaro", 
"Campobasso", "Enna"), `Average amount` = c(2456.92, 2444.58, 
2363.48, 2341.57, 2334.63, 2334.01, 2323.97, 2310.46, 2259.03, 
2242.38), `Nominal Difference` = c(1006.8, 909.62, 1016.28, 980.7, 
1157.25, 1077.51, 1010.32, 1532.79, 1106.31, 922.35), `%` = c(40.97, 
37.2, 42.99, 41.88, 49.56, 46.16, 43.47, 66.34, 48.97, 41.13), 
    `Real Wage` = c(27.51, 27.37, 26.46, 26.22, 26.14, 26.13, 
    26.02, 25.87, 25.29, 25.11), `Real Difference` = c(11.27, 
    10.18, 11.38, 10.98, 12.95, 12.06, 11.31, 17.16, 12.38, 10.32
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: You can create a new variable using an f-string. Something along the lines of `xy["new_variable"] = f"{xy["Nominal Difference"] (xy["%"]) %}"`. You may need to do some rounding and such to get the exact output.

Comment: `with(df, sprintf("%i (+%0.1f%%)", \`Nominal Difference\`, \`Real Wage\`))`

Comment: hi @r2evans , i've tried your code, but R replies <<Error in sprintf("%i (+%0.1f%%)", `Nominal Difference`, `Real Wage`) :   invalid format '%i'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects >>

Comment: Okay, well, it looks like an integer so I assumed it. Use `%s` instead. io_boh, we've had many side-bars about sharing usable and realistic data, please please please use `dput`?!?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik:  I think you are thinking of some other language (Python?) not R.

Comment: I think it would be really cool to import some of the glue-like functionality of python's f-strings into base R! (Finally a good reason to change the `Depends: R (>= ...)` in my packages!)

Comment: @r2evans i've uploaded `dput`. Your command works, but if I try to add these new variable to my dataset using `mutate`  << f <- mutate(`Nominal` = with(f, sprintf("%s (+%0.1f%%)", `Nominal Difference`, `Real Wage`))) `>> R replies <<
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character" >>

Comment: @io_boh, for _that_ `\`Differenza Nominale\``, I'd likely use ` `%f`-variant to make sure you get the number of decimals on that number as well, perhaps `"%.0f (%+0.1f%%)"`?

Comment: Don't use `with(f, ...)`, just use `mutate(Nominal = sprintf(...))`. That was me demonstrating the use of `sprintf` on its own without needing to use `dataset$` twice internally (I think it looks/reads easier).

Comment: @r2evans it works. Is there a way to align vertically these values in `Nominal` now? because the real wages ( according with their amounts) have different lenght, for example 2412.34 is longer than 765.1 , hence when I paste the percentages some of them are not in line  in the cells of the table (vertically speaking)

Comment: Whoops, @user2554330 I think you're right. What was I thinking? :sweat: Luckily r2evans has this covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste0()` inside `mutate()` and adjust the decimals with `sprintf()` and the padding with `stringr::str_pad()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

mydat <- tribble(~ `City Name`, ~ `Nominal Difference`,   ~`%`,
                 "Barletta", 1007, 41.0,
                 "Caserta",  910, 37.2
)

mydat %>% 
  mutate(`Nominal Difference` = paste0(
    str_pad(
      `Nominal Difference`,
      width = max(nchar(`Nominal Difference`))),
    sprintf(" (+%.1f%%)",`%`))
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   `City Name` `Nominal Difference`   `%`
#>   <chr>       <chr>                <dbl>
#> 1 Barletta    "1007 (+41.0%)"       41  
#> 2 Caserta     " 910 (+37.2%)"       37.2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: hi @TimTeaFan ! Also your code works fine! Is there a way to align vertically these values in `Nominal Difference` now? because the real wages ( according with their amounts) have different lenght, for example 2412.34 is longer than 765.1 , hence when I paste the percentages some of them are not in line in the cells of the table (vertically speaking)

Comment: @io_boh: Yes its possible with `stringr::str_pad()`, see my updated answer!

Comment: it works, but now the % simbol at the end of each number doesn't appear anymore... I have ( +41.0) , (  +37.2), ( +43.0) etc.

Comment: We need to add an `%` inside `sprintf`.

Comment: it is perfect now! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

From my comment:

```r
with(dataset, sprintf("%.0f (%+0.1f%%)", `Nominal Difference`, `Real Wage`)) 
#  [1] "1007 (+27.5%)" "910 (+27.4%)"  "1016 (+26.5%)" "981 (+26.2%)"  "1157 (+26.1%)" "1078 (+26.1%)" "1010 (+26.0%)"
#  [8] "1533 (+25.9%)" "1106 (+25.3%)" "922 (+25.1%)"
```

If you need to align each substring, `sprintf` supports space-padding with a leading zero, and change between left/right padding with a negation:

```
     '-' Left adjustment of converted argument in its field.

     '0' For numbers, pad to the field width with leading zeros. For
          characters, this zero-pads on some platforms and is ignored
          on others.
```

I don't think we can use space-padding on a number, but if we format each one individually, we can call `sprintf` *again* on the resulting strings.

```r
with(dataset,
  sprintf("%-6s %6s", sprintf("%.0f", `Nominal Difference`),
  sprintf("(%0+.1f)", `Real Wage`))
)
#  [1] "1007   (+27.5)" "910    (+27.4)" "1016   (+26.5)" "981    (+26.2)" "1157   (+26.1)" "1078   (+26.1)" "1010   (+26.0)"
#  [8] "1533   (+25.9)" "1106   (+25.3)" "922    (+25.1)"
```

---

Data

```r
dataset <- structure(list("City Name" = c("Barletta", "Caserta", "Avellino", "Lecce", "Benevento", "Isernia", "L'Aquila", "Catanzaro", "Campobasso", "Enna"), "Average amount" = c(2457L, 2445L, 2363L, 2342L, 2335L, 2334L, 2324L, 2310L, 2259L, 2242L), "Nominal Difference" = c(1007L, 910L, 1016L, 981L, 1157L, 1078L, 1010L, 1533L, 1106L, 922L), "%" = c(41, 37.2, 43, 41.9, 49.6, 46.2, 43.5, 66.3, 49, 41.1), "Real Wage" = c(27.5, 27.4, 26.5, 26.2, 26.1, 26.1, 26, 25.9, 25.3, 25.1), "Real Difference" = c(11.3, 10.2,  11.4, 11, 13, 12.1, 11.3, 17.2, 12.4, 10.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: You can put the + sign in the format, and it would handle negatives as well, i.e. `"%s (%+0.1f%%)"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `unite`, for example

```
df %>%
  mutate(perc = sprintf("(+%.1f%%)", perc)) %>%
  unite(val, val:perc, remove = TRUE, sep = " ")
```

which outputs like

```
   id         val
1   1 68 (+68.7%)
2   2 39 (+38.4%)
3   3  1 (+77.0%)
4   4 34 (+49.8%)
5   5 87 (+71.8%)
6   6 43 (+99.2%)
7   7 14 (+38.0%)
8   8 82 (+77.7%)
9   9 59 (+93.5%)
10 10 51 (+21.2%)
```

**Dummy Data**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  val = sample(100, 10),
  perc = 100 * runif(10)
)

# > df
#    id val     perc
# 1   1  68 68.70228
# 2   2  39 38.41037
# 3   3   1 76.98414
# 4   4  34 49.76992
# 5   5  87 71.76185
# 6   6  43 99.19061
# 7   7  14 38.00352
# 8   8  82 77.74452
# 9   9  59 93.47052
# 10 10  51 21.21425
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(percent, ~ str_c("(", .x, "%)"))) %>% 
  unite("nominal_difference", c(nominal_difference, percent), sep = " ") 

# A tibble: 10 × 5
   city_name  average_amount nominal_difference real_wage real_difference
   <chr>               <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 Barletta             2457 1007 (41%)              27.5            11.3
 2 Caserta              2445 910 (37.2%)             27.4            10.2
 3 Avellino             2363 1016 (43%)              26.5            11.4
 4 Lecce                2342 981 (41.9%)             26.2            11  
 5 Benevento            2335 1157 (49.6%)            26.1            13  
 6 Isernia              2334 1078 (46.2%)            26.1            12.1
 7 L'Aquila             2324 1010 (43.5%)            26              11.3
 8 Catanzaro            2310 1533 (66.3%)            25.9            17.2
 9 Campobasso           2259 1106 (49%)              25.3            12.4
10 Enna                 2242 922 (41.1%)             25.1            10.3
```